# Live search on a paginated list in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do you implement a live search with a paginated list, in jquery?  I have a list of friends within a DIV, but the friends are loaded 15 at a time (endless scroll).  I wanted to provide a textbox on top, so that they can filter the search.  However, what if they search for something that's not loaded yet?  What's the basic approach I'd have to take?  For example, let's say John and Jack are the only ones loaded so far and the user types in 'sa', how do I bring up the names starting with 'sa'?

Thanks.

```
<div id="friends">
   <input id="search" type="text" /> 
   <ul>
      <li>John</li>
      <li>Jack</li>
       .
       .
       .
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What is behind your requests? How do you fetch/load your friends?

Comment: No, I know how to fetch friends via Ajax get. In this scenario though my friendlist gets loaded 10 at a time due to paging. Once I thrown in a textbox for searching the list, if I have all my data loaded, then search via jquery is fast and doable. But if I don't have all my items loaded yet, then I'd have to go to the server to fetch the friends whose names start with the letters typed into the textbox, that wouldn't be as quick as if I had all my data loaded before searching, and also I wont; be able to show a live list of search results while they type. I wanted to know how others do this

Comment: Yeah, thats the reason for my question. If we don't know how you get your friends (in what kind of format JSON, XML or similar and how you provide them) no one can give you an aceptable answer.

Comment: I was looking for a generalized approach, so the format or any other specifics should not matter.

Comment: Then, so I think, is the answer from @isherwood your answer?!

Comment: @isherwood's answer will work for me, but it'll be a last resort.  I want to know how to build one myself.

Comment: Search the web, read some tutorials and don't be too shy to inhale documentations. If you stuck though come back, provide us your code (and problem) and we'll see what we can do for you!

Answer (score 1):

DataTables has all that sort of thing built in. It does require that your data be in a properly-formatted table, however.

http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/zero_config.html

Comment: Thanks @isherwood.  Though I was interested in knowing what's the basic approach behind doing something like this.

Comment: The reason your question was downvoted is because it's too vague and general for SO. You haven't provided any sample code or told us what you've tried. Not many folks are inclined to guess at what you're doing, and then to write code or lengthy explanations.

Comment: Oh ok..I thought my description was straightforward.  I've updated it.